Importance of Ph.D. Degree Title in Career Outcomes
I attend a graduate school that has offers two Ph.D. degrees in mathematics: one as you would expect, and the other with an added concentration in mathematical biology. I gather that the department is rather known for its research group in mathematical biology. I have been told by some in the department that opting for the concentration in mathematical biology (which will be shown on the degree) could be perceived negatively outside of the narrow search for careers specifically concerned with mathematical biology. I suppose this owes to the perception that the degree with the concentration is less rigorous and more hyperspecialized than the standard mathematics Ph.D. degree.
However, others in the department have claimed that the precise title of the degree is basically irrelevant, and what truly matters is the coursework you have completed and the ability to sell your own skillset and experience to whatever prospective employer you happen to find yourself interviewing with. As someone who is interested in applied math (though not only mathematical biology), is there merit to the viewpoint that I could be overlooked for positions due to having a specialized degree title? Would it be a mistake to opt for the concentration if I still feel that there is a possibility I would like to work in a different subfield of applied math? Thanks in advance.

Are you focused on careers within academia (i.e. university faculty) or outside?

Presumably the difference is more about what you actually do during your PhD studies rather than the "degree title". If genuinely you do your PhD in financial mathematics but for some reason your official PhD title says "PhD in Mathematical Biology", you will most likely not be overlooked for academic positions in financial mathematics. But in reality, if you opt for the path where your title says "PhD in Mathematical Biology", you are not in fact going to work on financial mathematics, and the reason why people will overlook you for such positions will not be the "degree title".

Nobody cares what it says on your diploma. They care what your papers and thesis cover.

The specifics of the PhD might be important in obtaining your first position, but after that no one is likely to care and it will depend on what you do and your research interests at that time. Once you are a bit established you can set your own goals and research program.
And if you do focus on mathematical biology then the dissertation, CV, transcripts, letters, etc. will make that clear to anyone interested whether or not the diploma specifies biology.
All (almost) PhDs are quite narrow in scope, though the diploma doesn't always state the specifics of the narrow field of the doctoral research.
I'd guess that as long as it is still called a PhD that it won't matter. For a bio related job you just stress that you are well qualified to research that. A piece of paper doesn't change that.


[I]s there merit to the viewpoint that I could be overlooked for positions due to having a specialized degree title?

In the strictest sense, the answer to this question is "yes". In the comparative sense, a slight difference in the title of your degree is effectively irrelevant next to other aspects of your future applications.
If someone is trying to hire a particularly theory-focused mathematician, you're simply never going to be a fit for that position with an applied focus, no matter what your degree title. As long as it's clear that you can write proofs correctly by the time you're applying for your next job (if that job is academic), you're as good as you're going to be on this axis.

Would it be a mistake to opt for the concentration if I still feel that there is a possibility I would like to work in a different subfield of applied math?

An approach to answering this question is to look at the underlying differences between taking this concentration and not taking it in terms of coursework. If the courses you will be required to take mesh well with other possible areas you would be comfortable working in, that's good. Otherwise, pivoting from one distinct specialization to another later usually isn't impossible, but will cost some quantity of time.

The OP doesn't suggest interest in "theory-focused" (i.e. pure) math, but only the possibility of other applied fields.

@Buffy The OP mentions some context regarding whether a bio concentration will be perceived as "less rigorous"-- I can of course be wrong, but I understand their anecdotes to be a symptom in math of a stereotype that anything interacting with application areas is "less rigorous" in general. What I'm trying to convey in my answer is that people with this outlook do exist and job searches tilted towards theory do as well, but they're unlikely to be impacted one way or another by the title of a concentration on an applicant's degree.
